# Is the Java Logging property 'com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.log' a physical file somewhere?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, java.util.logging, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have configured Java Logging to push log records to Stackdriver. I have a question about this LoggingHandler property.

```
# default : java.log
#com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingHandler.log=??
```

My Stackdriver Logs View shows each entry has an attribute called:

logName: "projects/[my project id]/logs/java.log"

Is this just a *logical* name or does it have a *physical* file somewhere in my Google Cloud Platform? I cannot find it in Cloud Storage or FileStore.

If it is a physical file somewhere in a shared place, how do I get to it and, does each of my cluster nodes need a unique value for it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware of, these are more a kind of logical files because you can access them but exclusively on Stackdriver Logging, in other words, there is no storage or physical path where you can check those logs, but you can use the download option on Stackdriver.

Greetings!